# RethinkDB with more throughput?

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, rethinkdb

I am looking to build out a realtime pubsub database backend. RethinkDB is actually a perfect package for what I need, mainly because of it's very low latency changefeeds. But RethinkDB seems to be a DB that you can expect about 10k-20k inserts per second on two machines. Whereas I have seen some postings claim people are getting 1 million inserts per second on DB's like Cassandra with comparable hardware, but Cassandra doesn't have the realtime changefeeds feature.

So my question is, is there another DB, or combination of open source systems, which can provide the low latency changefeed functionality of RethinkDB, but enable it to occur on a scale much much larger than RethinkDB? Both quantity of inserts per second, and amount of users that are subscribed to change feeds are both important requirements that need to be high as possible.

Comment: I would think Redis (for speed) or Kafka (for correctness) would be a good fit but this is kinda opinion based. fwiw 10k/20k a sec isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDB might still fit your needs if you can scale out to a robust cluster (lots of nodes). Below is a link to a report they generated with performance metrics scaling up to a 16-node cluster.

https://rethinkdb.com/docs/2-1-5-performance-report/